# oracle query to convert number format to date format or vice versa

Tags: oracle

In DB, date is stored in number format (Mon Jul 07 14:41:40 IST 2014
  is stored as 1404724300383), I need a query to convert number to date to compare with the sysdate, or from sysdate to number format. How can we convert the date to number or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the number is a sequencial one based on specific rule. You need to know the rule first.

- Get the rule

a) 07 July 2014 = 1404724300383; 07 July 2013 = ? (assume 1404700000000)

b) Assume value 0 mapping to one day, Day1

c) two formulas 1404724300383 = (07 July 2014 - Day1) * RULE; 1404700000000 = (07 July 2013 - Day1)*Rule;

Then, Rule = 24300383/365 and Day 1 = 1 Jan 1900 + 41285/(1404724300383/1404700000000*41460/((1404724300383/1404700000000)-1))

where 41825 is the days between 07 July 2014 and 1 Jan 1900)
41460 is the days between 07 July 2013 and 1 Jan 1900)

- Use the Rule and Day1 to get what you need

select Day1 + [query column]/Rule from Your_Table;